# How to make my react-dnd droppable component draggable too?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have this dustbin component that accepts some numbers. But after accepting numbers, I want to drag that box too rather than picking numbers from the left and right side of my window.
Here's my current Dustbin.js code:

```
import { memo } from 'react';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
const style = {
    height: '6rem',
    width: '6rem',
    marginRight: '5px',
    padding: '1rem',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    lineHeight: 'normal',
};
export const Dustbin = memo(function Dustbin({ shouldAccept, accept, lastDroppedItem, onDrop, }) {
    const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
        accept,
        drop: onDrop,
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: monitor.isOver(),
            canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
        }),
    });
    const isActive = isOver && canDrop;
    let backgroundColor = '#CBD5E1';
    if (isActive) {
        backgroundColor = 'darkgreen';
    }
    else if (canDrop) {
        backgroundColor = 'darkkhaki'
    }
    return (<div ref={drop} className='flex justify-center items-center' role="Dustbin" style={{ ...style, backgroundColor }}>
        {
            lastDroppedItem && lastDroppedItem?.name == shouldAccept && `${shouldAccept}`}
    </div>);
});
```

Here's a picture of what my application looks like right now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make `ondrop` components draggable, just put an `ondrag` next to ondrop like this:

```
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    type: 'box-drag',
    item: () => {
      return { number: YourBoxNumber };
    },
    collect: (monitor: any) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
```

then update your `useDrop` to accept the dragging type `box-type` you may need to write another `usedrop` with the dragging type `box-type` for this.

```
  const [{ handlerId }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: 'box-drag',
    collect(monitor) {
      return {
        handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId(),
      };
    },
    hover(item: { number }, monitor) {
      // do something on hover
    },
    drop(item: { number }, monitor: DropTargetMonitor) {
      // do something when another box dropped on it.
    },
  });
```

After all

```
drag(drop(ref))
```

`ref` is the ref for your box (currently your ref is `drop`, after it's dragging the name shall be updated either).